# python json.normalize error if some subrecords do not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested

I need to help with normalize columns in pandas DataFrame.
This is input

```py
df = {0:[{'Code' : 1,'Category' : 'X'},
         {'Code' : 2,'Category' : 'Y','snapshots' : [{'Address': {'City': 'City B'}}] },
         {'Code' : 3,'Category' : 'Z','snapshots' : [{'Address': {'City': 'City C'}}] }
         ]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

My code:

```py
df_1 = pd_json.json_normalize(df[0],
                              meta=["Code"],
                              record_path=["snapshots"],
                              record_prefix="snapshots.",
                              errors="ignore"
                              )
df_2 = (df_1.drop('snapshots.Address', 1)
                    .assign(**df_1["snapshots.Address"].dropna()
                    .apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('snapshots.Address.')))
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 5, in 
>       errors="ignore"
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py",
>   line 267, in json_normalize
>       _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py",
>   line 244, in _recursive_extract
>       recs = _pull_field(obj, path[0])
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py",
>   line 189, in _pull_field
>       result = result[spec]
>
> KeyError: 'snapshots'

There is missing "snapshots" in DataFrame for "Code=1". 
My idea is add "snapshots" to places in DataFrame, where it is missing. But I do not know how to do it.

Expected result:

```py
df_2
Out[617]: 
   Code snapshots.Address.City
0     1                    NaN
1     2                 City B
2     3                 City C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working since you have one value without `snapshots` key, so you'd need to use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0]).iloc[:, 1:]
df['snapshots.Address.City'] = df.pop('snapshots').apply(lambda x: x[0]['Address']['City'] if x is not np.nan else x)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Code snapshots.Address.City
0     1                    NaN
1     2                 City B
2     3                 City C
```

Comment: Thank you @U10-Forward. I try to modify it in my Case, but without success. If there will be more columns in "snapshots", not only "Address". Moreover columns in "Address" not only "City". So columns in result will be, for example: Code, snapshots.columnA, snapshots.columnB, snapshots.columnC, snapshots.Address.City, snapshots.Address.Street, snapshots.Address.postcode, snapshots.Address.Number, etc. ??